# How to catch the file object so that it can be sent as an attachment

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, smtp, export-to-csv

I am unable to catch f - file that is the result file which I need to push as attachment it's showing unable to find path. I even tried to pull out the path manually but then if I run this program more than once it might pick some other result file

Importing libraries and upload test files:

```
import urllib.request
import csv
import win32com.client as win32
c=0
data=open("test.csv",encoding='utf-8')
csv_data=csv.reader(data)
data_lines=list(csv_data)
f=open('result.csv','w',newline='',encoding='utf-8')
thewriter=csv.writer(f)
```

After reading test file a format for result file is created with below mentioned 3 columns

```
thewriter.writerow(['server','URL','Result'])

for row in data_lines:
    try:
        webUrl  = urllib.request.urlopen(str(row[1]))
        p=int(webUrl.getcode())
        if p==200:
            thewriter.writerow([row[0],row[1],'Success'])
            c+=1
            print(c,'Done')

    except ConnectionResetError:
        thewriter.writerow([row[0],row[1],'Connection Failed'])
        c+=1
        print(c,'Done')

    except:
        thewriter.writerow([row[0],row[1],'URL Failed'])
        c+=1
        print(c,'Done')
```

Till now url status have been inserted and now below code sends to the mail:

```
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = 'E-mail'
mail.Subject = 'TEST'
mail.Body = 'This is a test'
```

This is where the problem lies

```
attachment  = r'f'
mail.Attachments.Add(attachment)
mail.Send()
f.close()
data.close()
print("Process completed")
```

Comment: Your passing the string `'f'` to `Attachments.add`.  What kind of object does `Attachments.add` expect?

Comment: a csv file i want to attach the result.csv file which is created